# PhoneGap Plugin navigator.notification.alert Error in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

If I use `navigator.notification.alert` method inside of a controller it works like this:

```
angular.module('app.login')
  .controller('LoginController',LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = [...];

function LoginController(...){
  ...
  navigator.notification.alert(
      'Username or Password incorrect. Please try again.',// message
      null,             // callback
      'Freedom Nation', // title
      'Ok'              // buttonName
  );
  ...
}
```

But if I use it in a factory, I get `$digest already in progress error`. The factory:

```
angular
    .module('blocks.logger')
    .factory('logger', logger);

logger.$inject = ['$log'];

function logger($log) {
...
navigator.notification.alert(
    'Username or Password incorrect. Please try again.',// message
    null,             // callback
    'Freedom Nation', // title
    'Ok'              // buttonName
);
...
}
```

Why am I getting this error in the `factory` but not in the `controller`?

Error Message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```